# Firestore Emulators unit tests with jest, not a valid host error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, firebase-tools

So the emulators are up and running everything is fine but when I start the test the index.spec.ts always fails with the same reason. I tried everything I can found but still stuck here, any help is appreciated.

[That's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG4DM.png)

Value for argument "FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST" is not a valid host.

```
 npm run test

 > test
 > set FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080 && jest --watchAll -- 
 detectOpenHandles
 PASS  src/tests/security_rules.spec.ts
 FAIL  src/tests/index.spec.ts
 ● Test suite failed to run

Value for argument "FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST" is not a valid host.

  at Object.validateHost (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:129:19)
  at Firestore.validateAndApplySettings (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:488:24)
  at new Firestore (node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:413:14)
  at initFirestore (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/firestore-internal.js:104:12)
  at new FirestoreService (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/firestore-internal.js:27:32)
  at node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/index.js:76:94
  at node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-app.js:174:63
  at FirebaseApp.Object.<anonymous>.FirebaseApp.ensureService_ (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-app.js:204:43)
  at FirebaseApp.Object.<anonymous>.FirebaseApp.getOrInitService (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/app/firebase-app.js:174:21)
  at getFirestore (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/index.js:76:40)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       7 passed, 7 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.981 s, estimated 4 s
Ran all test suites.
```

I expected that both test to run without errors, the exact same system works on MAC without any issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.